# Git rebase without re-adding dropped commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have two branches:

```
Branch1:  (old) A B C D E F G H (new)
Branch2:  (old) A B   D E F     (new)
```

Notice that the C was dropped from Branch 2 and then G & H were added to Branch1.

I want to rebase Branch1 on Branch2, but I don't want the C to re-appear since it was dropped from Branch2.  I only want to fast forward pushes to Branch1 from Branch2. C must be gone from history.

My broken approach:

```
git checkout Branch1
git rebase Branch2

Branch1:  (old) A B D E F C G H (new)
```

What doesn't work:

- I don't have exact commits, I am automating the whole thing, so I can't use

  - `git rebase --onto Branch2 F H`
  - `git cherry-pick G H`
- I only have two branch names, that's all.

I am mainly looking for some way to tell git rebase to only pick fast-forwarding commits.  Is it possible?

Comment: As written, your branches cannot exist as described. Maybe if you change Branch2 commits to be `D' E' F'` to indicate they are similar to their corresponding non-prime commit, but with a different ID (and likely different commited times too). Regardless of what you call it, fast forward will be impossible.

Comment: After a re-read, I think I understand what your goal is, but I'm really getting thrown off by your use of "fast-forward", which actually means resetting one branch to point to the same commit as another branch. You can't do that if the branches have diverged like in your example.

Comment: Note if your goal is to just have another branch without a commit, it would be much easier to deal with if you reverted that commit on the other branch, rather than remove it. Then you could rebase (or merge) easily every time without needing to get fancy.

Comment: one way to have `rebase` work without external information is to leave `C` in the history, and have another `revert C` commit -- I don't recommend having to manage a history like that, I'm just mentioning it as a way to make git rebase "aware" that `C` was already part of Branch2 history.

Comment: "I am automating the whole thing" : can you please give more context on that ? you will somehow have to feed information to this automated procedure that `C` should be dropped.

Comment: If I understand well and you want `A B D E F G H`, it should be `git checkout Branch1` then `git rebase --onto Branch2 F_of_branch1_hash` (should work with any commit between D and F also if changes are identical in the 2 branches) . If you don't have the hash but know how many commits you want to rebase: `git rebase --onto Branch2 Branch1~2`. If you have **just** branch names as information, that's impossible.

Comment: @LeGEC I feel like your first comment is basically the same as my last one. And I agree with you. Hehe.

Comment: so here's the automation.  we have chained branches.  like Branch1, Branch2, Branch3.   commits go from 1 to 3.   Promoting commits is through testing.  so let's say 10 commits start from branch1,  maybe only 7 passed commits will land Branch2. and only 3 will land in Branch3.   the failed commits are dropped using bisection.   Meanwhile the more 5 commits can land in Branch1.   Branch1 would be rebased on Branch2, Branch2 would be rebased on Branch3.  In rebasing, I don't want the failed commits to re-appear in earlier branches. Only new commits should be kept.

Comment: @JayJoshi: find a way to mark up to what point you have validated commits on `Branch1` (for example: create a branch `integration/Branch1` ?) then use `git rebase --onto`: `git rebase --onto Branch2 integration/Branch1 Branch1` (<- anything that allows you to point at that specific commit - `F` on Branch1 in your example - is fine) After that, update integration/Branch1; for example, still using a branch: `git branch -f integration/Branch1 Branch2`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to somehow keep track of the point in the history of `Branch1` which was reviewed and either integrated or discarded, and then use it to run `git rebase --onto Branch2 <that_point> Branch1`.

---

one example could be to keep a reference to that commit, for example

- a branch: `git branch integration/Branch1 <F>` (meaning "commit F on Branch1")
- or a ref for which you choose a name:

  ```
  git update-ref --create-reflog -m "<some message for your reflog>" \
         refs/integration/Branch1 <F>
  ```

---

when you integrate new commits on Branch2, you should update that reference.
Say you include commit `G` on Branch2:

- `git branch -f integration/Branch1 G`
- or:

  ```
  git update-ref --create-reflog -m "<some message for your reflog>" \
         refs/integration/Branch1 <G>
  ```

---

when you want to rebase Branch1 (or try to, at least), you can use that name:

```
git rebase --onto Branch2 integration/Branch1 Branch1
```

if this succeeds, you should then update the "integration" reference:

```
git branch -f integration/Branch1 Branch2
```

or

```
git update-ref --create-reflog -m "<some message for your reflog>" \
    refs/integration/Branch1 Branch2
```